# How to install TShell for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Microsoft has introduced TShell recently.

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Phone_Testing/Installing_and_configuring_TShell

The links to TShell installation aren't there.

Can anybody help me to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to download this from Microsoft, using your OEM account.

There are more detailed instructions on MSDN at https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Getting_Started/Preparing_for_Windows_Phone_development.

Comment: Is their no way that I can download it without OEM account. I need it to connect to a remote VM on which I have installed WP8 so that I can install an app on that remote VM.

Comment: Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/mobile/preparing-for-windows-mobile-development , but yes, you may need and account to download that SDK